# Customizing new Android MaterialButton for Google SignIn

Tags: android, material-components

Before migrating to `AndroidX / MaterialComponents`, I had customized the `Buttons` to look like this.

[image]
Custom `Google SignIn button`:

```
 < Button 
    android: id = "@+id/customGoogleSignInBtn"
    style = "@style/SocialLoginBtnStyle"
    android: background = "@color/googleColor"
    android: drawableStart = "@drawable/logo_google_sign_in_btn_normal_46dp"
    android: drawableLeft = "@drawable/logo_google_sign_in_btn_normal_46dp"
    android: foreground = "?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android: paddingStart = "1dp"
    android: paddingLeft = "1dp"
    android: paddingEnd = "1dp"
    android: paddingRight = "1dp"
    android: text = "@string/google_sign_in"
    android: textStyle = "bold" /  >
```

Upon migrating to new `MaterialComponents`, I couldn't customize the `MaterialButton` to look the same way.

The specific challenge I'm facing is, I couldn't set `Google` icon, and also the left padding by default is way too much.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
    app:iconTintMode="src_atop"
    app:icon="@drawable/logo_google_sign_in_btn_normal_46dp"
    android:text="@string/google_sign_in"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/googleColor"
    app:iconPadding="0dp" />
```

How can I customize this? Couldn't find much help for `MaterialButton`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up inheriting from `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton` rather than just `Button`.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/customGoogleSignInBtn"
            style="@style/SocialLoginBtnStyle"
            android:background="@color/googleColor"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/logo_google_sign_in_btn_normal_46dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/logo_google_sign_in_btn_normal_46dp"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingStart="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:text="@string/google_sign_in"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1):

first, are you using MaterialButton library to get the google sign in button?
if yes I suggest you to change the version of the library to the newest one.

Or why not using Shobitpuri Library instead? To add the library, If you are using Android 3+ then instead using compile, use Implementation Instead.

```
Implementation 'com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0'
```

And for the XML file:

```
<com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons.GoogleSignInButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="@string/google_sign_up"
    app:isDarkTheme="true" />
```

You can see the expected result here [CustomGoogleSignInButtonThemeDarkShobitpuri](https://github.com/shobhitpuri/custom-google-signin-button)

Comment: Thank you. I could use the library, but what about customizing for say Facebook button?

Comment: For facebook, you need a different library. using this library will help you:

    ` implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'`


But first, the same with Google, You need To register your app to https://developers.facebook.com/. you get your app id there.

You can visit this site https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/ for more details.

Or if you want an example of an app that have Google Sign In and Facebook Sign In, I actually have it, just tell me if you need it.

Comment: Sure, glad to helped.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same and somehow android studio was not recognizing my icon and showing white image same as your. What I did was to add image asset from andorid studio as below

```
Right click drawable -> new -> Image Assets -> select icon type as action bar and tabs icon -> asset type to image and select your image file.
```

Now add this as icon to your material button as below

```
app:icon="@drawable/ic_close"
app:iconSize="28dp"
```

Regarding the more left padding, it is due to style, check the image below

[image]
[image]

To remove this padding, remove button style and set `paddingLeft` value in xml

```
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to add Google SignIn Button.

**Add Gradle:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

**Add Button in XML:**

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buttonSize="1"/>
```

**It will look something like this:**
    [image]

Comment: Thank you. I know this, but I wanted to learn about customising the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this and quit tint icon for show real color

```
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
  app:iconTint="@null
```

Example

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/idGoogle"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:icon="@drawable/ic_google"
  app:iconTint="@null"/>
```

[icon with real color shows black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54637591/icon-with-real-color-shows-black-background)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier approach provided with the button, no need to create different Buttons neither using separate libs. Also no need for setting the icon, as its already provided too.

1. set `app:buttonSize` for any of: 0 [`standard`], 1 [`wide`], 2 [`icon_only`]. In your case it would be `wide`
2. set `app:colorScheme` for any of: 0 [`dark`], 1[`light`], 2[`auto`]. In your case that would be `dark` so you get the blue background.

So to achieve what you have on the image you should set up button like this:

```xml
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:buttonSize="wide"
            app:colorScheme="dark" />
```